# Get the number of time Duplication count from excel sheet with particular Columns which is repeated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

In our case, we want to apply this thing to Addressline1 (Column D) and UNIT_NUMBER ( Column E).

If in excel there duplication of  addresline-1 and UNIT_NUMBER  column  in 2 times in rows then in output we need 2.

If there not any value combination for addresline-1 and UNIT_NUMBER , in that case, we want 0 in the output.

I have tried with =COUNTIFS($D1:$D2500,$D1,$E1:$E2500,$E1)>1 formula but this not work in below case

D                                        E

2                                        EmptyCell

2                                        EmptyCell

So, please help if anyone knows the solution to it.

[image: Excel columns example]

Comment: You probably just need to make your ranges static. `=COUNTIFS($D$1:$D$2500,$D1,$E$1:$E$2500,$E1)>1`

Comment: @hsan Yes You are right but range I will manage from my side